# How to associate file type .x_t with iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to associate files with specific extension with iOS App. I have successfully associated other file types like .obj, .stl, etc. using link: 
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

**But for files which have "_" underscore in the extension fail to get associated.  It is failing for files with extension .x_t**

Apple UTI guidelines say that
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE

> The UTI Character Set A uniform type identifier is a Unicode string
>   that usually contains characters in the ASCII character set. However,
>   only a subset of the ASCII characters are permitted. You may use the
>   Roman alphabet in upper and lower case (A–Z, a–z), the digits 0
>   through 9, the dot (“.”), and the hyphen (“-”). This restriction is
>   based on DNS name restrictions, set forth in RFC 1035.
>
> Uniform type identifiers may also contain any of the Unicode
>   characters greater than U+007F.
>
> Important: Any illegal character appearing in a UTI string—for
>   example, underscore ("_"), colon (":"), or space (" ")—will cause the
>   string to be rejected as an invalid UTI. At the API layer, no error is
>   generated for invalid UTIs.

So is there any way around to associate x_t files with the iOS App?

Comment: The UTI character set refers to the UTI, not the file extension. You cannot have an UTI that is e.g. com.you.x_t, but you should ba able to have a file extension of x_t set up for if. For UTI you could have com.you.x-t though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTI as com.you.x-t and file extension as x_t.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>x_t file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.you.x-t</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.item</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>x_t files</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.you.x-t</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>x_t</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

UTI: com.you.x_t & file extension x_t does not work

UTI: com.you.x-t & file extension x-t does not work